# after executing the mage bash file from the fedora command prompt I am getting "unexpected end of file"

Tags: bash, magento

I am using default magento mage file on fedora command prompt through following command:-

```
sh mage mage-setup
```

But I am getting following message over there:-

```
"unexpected end of file"
```

Can anyone help on this while I didn't make any change on this default magento file.

Comment: why are you using `sh ...`, can't you just do `mage mage-setup`? Good luck.

Comment: I also tried the same as well....

Comment: And I am getting "Command not found" message

Comment: and what happens if you use are hard-coded path to the executable, i.e. `/path/to/mage mage-setup`? Unless there is something else going on that you're not including in your question OR documentation for `magneto` specifically says to use `sh mage ...`, then you shouldn't need to use `sh ..`. Good luck.

Comment: /var/www/html/humanelement/mage mage-setup
-bash: /var/www/html/humanelement/mage: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
This is the message which I got after using full path

Comment: `^M` is an indicator that you have Windows file running in a Unix/Linux environment. `dos2unix myFile` will eliminate any `^M` chars in your file, and may solve your initial problem. You should try to find a tuturial about getting installed packages to run in Fedora. Good luck.